# Объединение списков

Tags: c, списки

Нужно написать функцию объединения списков. Я написал вот такой код, но прога крашится если во втором списке больше одного слова. Если изначально в первом листе ничего нет, то все слова запишутся нормально, то есть проблема начинается если первый список не пустой. Если просто поочередно вставлять узлы через pushSort работая в main(), то так же при записи более одного узла прога крашится.

```
void merge(list *r, list *l) {
    int i = 0;
    node *cur = l->head;
    while (i < l->size) {
        pushSort(cur, r);
        cur = cur->next;
        i++;
    }
}
```

ФУЛЛ КОД

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#define PATH "/Users/ivanrud/Desktop/Универ/Информатика/lab6/"
typedef struct node {
    char word[50];
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list {
    node *head;
    node *last;
    int size;
} list;

int isLetter(char c) {
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void pushSort(node *n, list *l) {
    if (l->size == 0) {
        l->head = n;
        l->last = n;
        l->size++;
    }
    else {
        node *cur = l->head;
        node *buf;
        while (1) {
            if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) == 0) {
                buf = cur->next;
                cur->next = n;
                cur->next->next = buf;
                l->size++;
                break;
            }
            else if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) > 0 && cur->next != NULL ) {
                if (strcmp(n->word, cur->next->word) < 0) {
                    buf = cur->next;
                    cur->next = n;
                    cur->next->next = buf;
                    l->size++;
                    break;
                }
                cur = cur->next;
                continue;
            }
            else if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) > 0 && cur->next == NULL) {
                buf = cur->next;
                cur->next = n;
                cur->next->next = buf;
                l->size++;
                break;
            }
            else if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) < 0 && cur == l->head) {
                buf = l->head;
                l->head = n;
                n->next = buf;
                l->size++;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}

void merge(list *r, list *l) {
    int i = 0;
    node *cur = l->head;
    while (i < l->size) {
        pushSort(cur, r);
        cur = cur->next;
        i++;
    }
}

void printList(list *l) {
    int i = 0;
    node* cur = l->head;
while (i < l->size) {
        printf("%s ", cur->word);
        cur = cur->next;
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    chdir(PATH);
    char str1[1000] = { '\0' };
    char str2[1000] = { '\0' };
    char str3[1000] = { '\0' };
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    FILE *S1, *S2, *S3;

    S1 = fopen("S1.txt", "r");
    if (S1 == NULL) {
        printf("Izvini :(");
    }
    else {
        while ((str1[i] = fgetc(S1)) != EOF) {
            i++;
        }
    } i = 0;

//LIST1
    node* Node1 = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
    list* list1 = (list*) malloc (sizeof(list));
    list1->last = NULL;
    list1->head = NULL;
    list1->size = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (isLetter(str1[i])) {
            Node1->word[j] = str1[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (isLetter(str1[i]) == 0 && isLetter(str1[i - 1]) == 1) {
            Node1->word[j] = '\0';
            pushSort(Node1, list1);
            j = 0;
            Node1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        }
        if (str1[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    S2 = fopen("S2.txt", "r");
    if (S2 == NULL) {
        printf("Izvini :(");
    }
    else {
        while ((str2[i] = fgetc(S2)) != EOF) {
            i++;
        }
    } i = 0;

//LIST2
    node* Node2 = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
    list* list2 = (list*) malloc (sizeof(list));
    list2->last = NULL;
    list2->head = NULL;
    list2->size = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (isLetter(str2[i])) {
            Node2->word[j] = str2[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (isLetter(str2[i]) == 0 && isLetter(str2[i - 1]) == 1) {
            Node2->word[j] = '\0';
            pushSort(Node2, list2);
            j = 0;
            Node2 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        }
        if (str2[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    S3 = fopen("S3.txt", "r");
    if (S3 == NULL) {
        printf("Izvini :(");
    }
    else {
        while ((str3[i] = fgetc(S3)) != EOF) {
            i++;
        }
    } i = 0;

//LIST3
    node* Node3 = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
    list* list3 = (list*) malloc (sizeof(list));
    list3->last = NULL;
    list3->head = NULL;
    list3->size = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (isLetter(str3[i])) {
            Node3->word[j] = str3[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (isLetter(str3[i]) == 0 && isLetter(str3[i - 1]) == 1) {
            Node2->word[j] = '\0';
            pushSort(Node3, list3);
            j = 0;
            Node3 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        }
        if (str3[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    list* listResult = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    listResult->head = NULL;
    listResult->last = NULL;
    listResult->size = 0;

    merge(listResult, list1);


    //merge(listResult, list2);
    //merge(listResult, list3);


    printList(listResult);


    free(Node1); free(list1);
    free(Node2); free(list2);
    free(Node3); free(list3);
    free(listResult);
    return 0;
}
```

@Igor

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#define PATH "/Users/ivanrud/Desktop/Универ/Информатика/lab6/"
typedef struct node {
    char word[50];
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list {
    node *head;
    node *last;
    int size;
} list;

int isLetter(char c) {
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void pushSort(node *n, list *l) {
    if (l->size == 0) {
        l->head = n;
        l->last = n;
        l->size++;
    }
    else {
        node *cur = l->head;
        node *buf;
        while (1) {
            if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) == 0) {
                buf = cur->next;
                cur->next = n;
                cur->next->next = buf;
                l->size++;
                break;
            }
            else if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) > 0 && cur->next != NULL ) {
                if (strcmp(n->word, cur->next->word) < 0) {
                    buf = cur->next;
                    cur->next = n;
                    cur->next->next = buf;
                    l->size++;
                    break;
                }
                cur = cur->next;
                continue;
            }
            else if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) > 0 && cur->next == NULL) {
                buf = cur->next;
                cur->next = n;
                cur->next->next = buf;
                l->size++;
                break;
            }
            else if (strcmp(n->word, cur->word) < 0 && cur == l->head) {
                buf = l->head;
                l->head = n;
                n->next = buf;
                l->size++;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}

void merge(list *r, list *l) {
    int i = 0;
    node *cur = l->head;
    while (i < l->size) {
        pushSort(cur, r);
        cur = cur->next;
        i++;
    }
}

void printList(list *l) {
    int i = 0;
    node* cur = l->head;
    while (i < l->size) {
        printf("%s ", cur->word);
        cur = cur->next;
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    chdir(PATH);
    char str1[] = {"bebra anton cast main"};
    char str2[] = {"gh sgh egiw gjwi ejgiwe jgiweg"};
    char str3[] = {"ihsg hdsgh skgsjgj sjdkg jsgh sdjg"};
    int i = 0, j = 0;


    printf("Input the 1string: ");


    printf("Input the 2string: ");
    gets(str2);

    printf("Input the 3string: ");
    gets(str3);

//LIST1

    node* Node1 = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
    Node1->next = NULL;
    list* list1 = (list*) malloc (sizeof(list));
    list1->last = NULL;
    list1->head = NULL;
    list1->size = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (isLetter(str1[i])) {
            Node1->word[j] = str1[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (isLetter(str1[i]) == 0 && isLetter(str1[i - 1]) == 1) {
            Node1->word[j] = '\0';
            pushSort(Node1, list1);
            j = 0;
            Node1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            Node1->next = NULL;


        }
        if (str1[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;



//LIST2
    node* Node2 = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
Node2->next = NULL;

    list* list2 = (list*) malloc (sizeof(list));
    list2->last = NULL;
    list2->head = NULL;
    list2->size = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (isLetter(str2[i])) {
            Node2->word[j] = str2[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (isLetter(str2[i]) == 0 && isLetter(str2[i - 1]) == 1) {
            Node2->word[j] = '\0';
            pushSort(Node2, list2);
            j = 0;
            Node2 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            Node2->next = NULL;

        }
        if (str2[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;


//LIST3
    node* Node3 = (node*) malloc (sizeof(node));
    list* list3 = (list*) malloc (sizeof(list));
    list3->last = NULL;
    list3->head = NULL;
    list3->size = 0;

    while (1) {
        if (isLetter(str3[i])) {
            Node3->word[j] = str3[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (isLetter(str3[i]) == 0 && isLetter(str3[i - 1]) == 1) {
            Node2->word[j] = '\0';
            pushSort(Node3, list3);
            j = 0;
            Node3 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        }
        if (str3[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    list* listResult = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    listResult->head = NULL;
    listResult->last = NULL;
    listResult->size = 0;

    merge(listResult, list1);


    //merge(listResult, list2);
    //merge(listResult, list3);


    printList(listResult);


    free(Node1); free(list1);
    free(Node2); free(list2);
    free(Node3); free(list3);
    free(listResult);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Код надо вставлять текстом. 2. [mcve]

Comment: Вам сразу станет легче программировать, если Вы прекратите употреблять *и думать* такие термины как "прога" и "крашится".

Comment: Есть подозрение, что с указателями проблемы. Т.к. если слова записывать в голый node (только что созданный) и далее этот node запихать в list, то все будет хорошо. Но опять же написав в функции cur->next = NULL получаю ту же проблемку.

Comment: У нас прекрасная, интеллектуальная беседа. Вы видите Ваш код и рассуждаете о его достоинствах и недостатках. Я не вижу Вашего кода и тоже рассуждаю о нем. Я как Жан-Клод Ван Дамм из "Кровавого Спорта" - сражаюсь, не видя противника.

Comment: Добавил полный код

Comment: Я правильно понял, что у вас 2 отсортированных списка и вы хотите вставить элементы первого списка во второй так, чтобы он после этого остался сортированным? / Если так, то: 1) Для такой задачи вы выбрали крайне неудачный алгоритм (2 сортированных списка должны сливаться за один проход(!!!)) 2) В вашем случае основная логическая ошибка в том, что после `pushSort(cur, r);` `cur->next` может  измениться. Поэтому надо было бы запоминать его в цикле **перед** вызовом `pushSort()` (однако, не забывайте о п.1 и лучше все это перепишите)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании узлов Вы нигде не присваиваете `NULL` указателю на следующий узел. Но в коде присутствует логика с проверкой этого указателя на `NULL`.

```
Node1 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
Node1->next = NULL; // !!!
...
Node2 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
Node2->next = NULL; // !!!
...
Node3 = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
Node3->next = NULL; // !!!
```

Напишите функцию `createNode`:

```
node* createNode()
{
  node* result = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  result->next = NULL;
  result->word[0] = '\0';
  return result;
}
```

Аналогично - `createList`.

---

Вы, надеюсь, понимаете, что память, распределенная на объекты `node`, в Вашем коде не освобождается - кроме трех.

---

Ваша функция `pushSort` портит узлы, меняя значения `cur->next`:

```
void merge(list *r, list *l) {
    int i = 0;
    node *cur = l->head, *next;
    while (i < l->size) {
        next = cur->next;
        pushSort(cur, r);
        cur = next;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86409/discussion-on-answer-by-igor--).

Comment: @Igor дай бог здоровья. Работает

Comment: @ИванРудь Пожалуйста. "Галочка" - слева от ответа.